# How to use vba to expand data ranges and copy and paste into mastersheet

Tags: excel, vba

This code aims to expand the context of importing copied data from multiple sources and paste in mastersheet. It also functions by being able to copy and paste from a internal master file and then use it to expand on new ranges.

```
Sub newloopfilemodule()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

    'First clear any original data
    Sheet1.Rows("2:50").ClearContents

    'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
    Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With FldrPicker
        .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

    'In Case of Cancel
    NextCode:
    myPath = myPath
    If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

    'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
    myExtension = "*.xls*"

    'Target Path with Ending Extention
    myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

    'Loop through each Excel file in folder
    Do While myFile <> ""
        'Set variable equal to opened workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
        'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents

        'Identify column number for Customer Parent ID, Country, and Region
        Dim custParentIDCol As Integer, custcidcol As Integer, customernamecol As Integer
        custParentIDCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Customer Parent ID", wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 0)
        custcidcol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Customer CID", wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 0)
        customernamecol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Customer Name", wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 0)

        'Count total number of rows in raw data file
        Dim rowNum As Integer
        rowNum = 2

        Dim topClients As String

        Dim filenamenow As String
        filenamenow = Mid(myFile, 1, InStr(1, myFile, ".") - 1)


    Dim outputrownum As Integer
    outputrownum = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
    outputrownum = outputrownum + 1



        Do While IsEmpty(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, custParentIDCol)) = False

            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wb.Sheets(1).Range(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, custParentIDCol), wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, custParentIDCol)), _
                                    wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, custParentIDCol)) = 1 Then

        Sheet1.Cells(outputrownum, 1) = outputrownum - 1
        Sheet1.Cells(outputrownum, 2) = filenamenow
        Sheet1.Cells(outputrownum, 3) = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, custParentIDCol)
        Sheet1.Cells(outputrownum, 4) = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, custcidcol)
        Sheet1.Cells(outputrownum, 5) = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, customernamecol)

                If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Columns(1), wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, custParentIDCol)) > 0 Then
                        topClients = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, custParentIDCol), Sheet2.Range("A:B"), 2, 0)
                         Sheet1.Cells(outputrownum, 6).Value = topClients
                        End If

                        outputrownum = outputrownum + 1
           End If
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Loop


        'Save and Close Workbook
        wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
        'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
        DoEvents
        'Get next file name
        myFile = Dir
    Loop

    'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    ResetSettings:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
    Sub combinedata()

    Dim projecttitlecol As Integer, effectivedatecol As Integer, productcol As Integer, matchingproject As Integer
        projecttitlecol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Project Title", Sheet3.Rows(1), 0)
        effectivedatecol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Effective Date", Sheet3.Rows(1), 0)
        productcol = WorksheetFunction.Match("Product", Sheet3.Rows(1), 0)

       Dim rowNum As Integer
       rowNum = 2

    Do While IsEmpty(Sheet1.Cells(rowNum, 2)) = False
       If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet3.Columns(1), Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, 2)) > 0 Then
        matchingproject = WorksheetFunction.Match(Sheet1.Cells(rowNum, 2), Sheet3.Columns(1), 0)

        Sheet1.Cells(rowNum, 7) = Sheet3.Cells(matchingproject, projecttitlecol)
        Sheet1.Cells(rowNum, 8) = Sheet3.Cells(matchingproject, effectivedatecol)
        Sheet1.Cells(rowNum, 9) = Sheet3.Cells(matchingproject, productcol)

    End If
    rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Loop

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub LoopAllExcelFilesInFolder()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim myPath As String
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim myExtension As String
    Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog

'First clear any original data
Sheet1.Rows("2:20").ClearContents

'Optimize Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With FldrPicker
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
End With

'In Case of Cancel
NextCode:
myPath = myPath
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings

'Target File Extension (must include wildcard "*")
myExtension = "*.xls*"

'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension)

'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> ""
    'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile)
    'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents

    'Identify column number for Customer Parent ID, Country, and Region
    Dim custParentIDCol As Integer, countryCol As Integer, regionCol As Integer
    custParentIDCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("UltimateID", wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 0)
    countryCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("ClntCntryCode", wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 0)
    regionCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("DomicileRegion", wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 0)
    ultimatenameCol = WorksheetFunction.Match("UltimateName", wb.Sheets(1).Rows(1), 0)

    'Count total number of rows in raw data file
    Dim rowNum As Integer
    rowNum = 2
    Do Until IsEmpty(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(rowNum, 1)) = True
        rowNum = rowNum + 1
    Loop
    rowNum = rowNum - 1

    wb.Sheets(1).Columns(custParentIDCol).Select 'specify the range which suits your purpose
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    'Count total number of unique clients impacted by project. If a client is APAC, count it.
    'If a client is unique, check if it's a top client. Add country.
    Dim totUniqueClients As Integer
    Dim totUniqueClientsAPAC As Integer
    Dim topClients As String
    Dim countries As String

    totUniqueClients = 0
    totUniqueClientsAPAC = 0
    topClients = ""
    countries = ""
    'Sort ultimate name by A to Z
   Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Columns(ultimatenameCol), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        End With

    For x = 2 To rowNum
        'Use COUNTIF to check if its a unique client. If unique, then add to totUniqueClient count.

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wb.Sheets(1).Range(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, custParentIDCol), wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, custParentIDCol)), _
                                wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, custParentIDCol)) = 1 Then
            totUniqueClients = totUniqueClients + 1
            'Then check if its APAC. If APAC, then add to totUniqueClientAPAC count
            If wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, regionCol) = "ASIA" Then
                totUniqueClientsAPAC = totUniqueClientsAPAC + 1
            End If
            'Then check if its a top client. If so, then add to topClient amount.
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheet2.Columns(1), wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, custParentIDCol)) > 0 Then
                If Len(topClients) > 0 Then
                    topClients = topClients & ", " & WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, custParentIDCol), Sheet2.Range("A1:D27"), 4, 0)
                Else
                    topClients = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, custParentIDCol), Sheet2.Range("A:D"), 4, 0)
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Next
        'Sort Country by A to Z
        Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
        Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Columns(countryCol), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, _
        DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        With Sheets(1).AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
        End With
        For x = 2 To rowNum
        'Use COUNTIF to check if its a unique country. If unique, then add to list of countries.

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(wb.Sheets(1).Range(wb.Sheets(1).Cells(2, countryCol), wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, countryCol)), _
                                wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, countryCol)) = 1 Then
                                If wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, regionCol) = "ASIA" Then
            If Len(countries) > 0 Then
                countries = countries & ", " & wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, countryCol)
            Else
                countries = wb.Sheets(1).Cells(x, countryCol)
            End If
            End If
        End If
    Next

    'Populate table in masterfile
    Dim tableRow As Integer
    tableRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Range("A:A"))
    tableRow = tableRow + 1


    Sheet1.Cells(tableRow, 1) = tableRow - 1
    Sheet1.Cells(tableRow, 2) = myFile
    Sheet1.Cells(tableRow, 3) = totUniqueClients
    Sheet1.Cells(tableRow, 4) = totUniqueClientsAPAC
    Sheet1.Cells(tableRow, 5) = topClients
    Sheet1.Cells(tableRow, 6) = countries

    'Save and Close Workbook
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=True
    'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents
    'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir
Loop

'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
ResetSettings:
Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```